# Can't remove or edit post after changing domain name

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently changed from one domain to another, in that new domain i copied my wordpress files/databases, everything was working fine, until i found some posts without any categories in it, when i tried to edit thoose "categoriless" posts i found a weird error, they can't be changed.

Any modifications that i do gets saved on database as a new post version ( Wordpress even warns me that there is a newer version of the post ), but i simply cannot use the new version.

The only thing that i managed to alter in post os the slug, after moving the post to trash the sluged is updated to something like this:
example.com/my-wordpress-post__trashed ( This post is still accessible in the website )

I deactiveted all the plugins and even changed the theme, but the problem persists, any ideas on where should i look to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I think you need to flush the permalinks.
Go to Settings -> Permalinks -> Save Changes.

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. export the contents of your Wordpress website
2. perform a new installation of Wordpress
3. import the exported data

If you change your domain name, then you have to change the site url of your wordpress installation.